# Boot script table modified, please contact vendor

Tags: boot, suspend

I had a variety of distros on this Lenovo G50-45 laptop, most recently Debian 8 and now Xubuntu 15.04 x64.
Whenever I want to put the system to sleep (suspend) I get the error message written in yellow:

> Warning!!! Boot script table modified, please contact your vendor!!!

The system sometimes suspends, but mostly it either reboots or shuts down.

I have 20 GB swap, so that's not an issue.

What could be wrong?