# suspend does not work more than once after reboot: ubuntu 15.04 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, 15.04, suspend

Hardware: Lenovo G40 , AMD x64

```
Ubuntu:
a@a-Lenovo-G40-45:~/fiddle/debugSuspend$ uname -a 
Linux a-Lenovo-G40-45 3.19.0-28-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 31 15:52:51 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
a@a-Lenovo-G40-45:~/fiddle/debugSuspend$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

**Issue:**

The first time I suspend (after reboot) , system works perfect. Both suspend and resume are fine. However 2nd time when I suspend , a yellow message appears `Warning!!! Boot script table modified, please contact your vendor!!!` after which system reboots.

I went through the `/var/log/syslog` for both cases but I don't see any difference in logs in both failure and success scenarios.

My firmware is updated to latest.

Any pointers please ? 
My issue is similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651481/boot-script-table-modified-please-contact-vendor) but there are no replies yet.

Earlier on this machine I had lubuntu 14.04.3 - there was no issue in suspend (But there was no dual boot either)

Answer (score 1):

I am having exactly the same issue on the same model laptop (with Xubuntu 14.04.3.)

I have found no other answers about this, but here are my surmises:

- Only UEFI has a boot script table.
- If your machine did not formerly do this, and the difference was Dual-booting, may I make a guess that you were formerly using legacy mode with Ubuntu booting through grub-pc, where now you are using UEFI mode with Ubuntu booting with grub-efi?
- I am not dual booting, but my install detected UEFI, and installed Xubuntu in UEFI mode. I was able to remove the echoes of the Windows install which the machine came with, so it is no longer even thinking about being dual-boot but it still has the described behaviour.
- **Therefore**, there appears to be a problem with EFI and suspend interfering with each other in Ubuntu on the Lenovo G50-45. Which seems to be restricted to this hardware. (I haven't seen any indication of this failure mode on any other hardware.)

I intend to try fiddling with the system to change it to legacy boot (that is, using grub-pc instead of grub-efi), but this may have to wait for when I have some time and mental capacity to undertake this task. (ie., not the week before Christmas.)

I am sorry this answer isn't of much use, but more information is better, and at least you know you aren't alone.

**Update:** I tried booting in legacy mode. No EFI evident in the OS, (no `/sys/firmware/efi/` was present) but this behaviour persisted. But then, there is still an EFI partition, so maybe I didn't clean it away thoroughly enough.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pm-utils/+bug/1528735